# can kibana used other data source(eg, a cache that contain elasticsearch result) instead of from elasticsearch directly?

Tags: elasticsearch, charts, data-visualization, kibana

I want to use Kibana to visualize data on a dashboard and make a lot of users on the internet can access the dashboard.

The problem is, Kibana will do a query every time, but the data will update about every 30 minutes, so it's a waste of cpu to do query evertime.

So, I want to cache the elasticsearch result in some place like redis and let the kinana to fetch data from the cache.

So:

1. is there any software that act as a proxy, which can accept kibana request and fetch data from cache and then send response to the kibana? In another word, I only want to use kibana as a UI framework and customize the data source
2. Is there any other UI framework that can easily visually elasticsearch query result?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need - Elasticsearch will cache the results.